# Getting invalid json when calling JSONSerialization in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to access a `URL` and parse the JSON output. Printing JSON in `utf8` encoding
Code:

```
let urlString:String = "https://developer.nrel.gov/api/.../"
    let pvURL = URL(string: urlString)
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:pvURL!) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)

        }catch let err {
            print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
```

Prints the following output. I try this JSON in an online JSON parser it fails. Gives error in the first line itself.

```
{"inputs":{"lat":"29.93","lon":"-95.61","system_capacity":"30.30","azimuth":"180","tilt":"40","array_type":"1","module_type":"1","losses":"10"},"errors":[],"warnings":[],"version":"1.0.1","ssc_info":{"version":45,"build":"Linux 64 bit GNU/C++ Jul  7 2015 14:24:09"},"station_info":{"lat":29.93000030517578,"lon":-95.62000274658203,"elev":41.0,"tz":-6.0,"location":"None","city":"","state":"Texas","solar_resource_file":"W9562N2993.csv","distance":964},"outputs":{"ac_monthly":[3480.57373046875,3440.078369140625,3992.6513671875,3977.071533203125,4074.91357421875,3701.75,3897.655517578125,4248.00390625,4023.283447265625,4157.29931640625,3605.156005859375,3342.12890625],"poa_monthly":[139.791015625,140.18896484375,164.8218536376953,164.47149658203125,173.2971649169922,159.90576171875,169.84793090820312,186.20114135742188,173.14492797851562,176.2291717529297,148.28318786621094,136.62326049804688],"solrad_monthly":[4.509387493133545,5.006748676300049,5.316833972930908,5.4823832511901855,5.590230941772461,5.3301920890808105,5.4789652824401855,6.00648832321167,5.77149772644043,5.684812068939209,4.94277286529541,4.407201766967773],"dc_monthly":[3644.867919921875,3606.52001953125,4179.85107421875,4158.3193359375,4252.9140625,3865.03369140625,4069.092041015625,4432.62744140625,4198.369140625,4336.99609375,3767.055419921875,3490.091064453125],"ac_annual":45940.55859375,"solrad_annual":5.293959140777588,"capacity_factor":17.308107376098633}}`
```

whereas if I access the `urlString` in a browser gives valid json:

```
{
"inputs": {
"lat": "29.93",
"lon": "-95.61",
"system_capacity": "30.30",
"azimuth": "180",
"tilt": "40",
"array_type": "1",
"module_type": "1",
"losses": "10"
},
"errors": [],
"warnings": [],
"version": "1.0.1",
"ssc_info": {
"version": 45,
"build": "Linux 64 bit GNU/C++ Jul  7 2015 14:24:09"
},
"station_info": {
"lat": 29.93000030517578,
"lon": -95.62000274658203,
"elev": 41,
"tz": -6,
"location": "None",
"city": "",
"state": "Texas",
"solar_resource_file": "W9562N2993.csv",
"distance": 964
},
"outputs": {
"ac_monthly": [
3480.57373046875,
3440.078369140625,
3992.6513671875,
3977.071533203125,
4074.91357421875,
3701.75,
3897.655517578125,
4248.00390625,
4023.283447265625,
4157.29931640625,
3605.156005859375,
3342.12890625
],
...
}
```

Comment: To get a better fix, can you print `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!` and post it here.

Comment: Your both JSON strings are valid those coming via browser and code as well. The JSON you pasted above which comes via code has a special char(`) at end of the JSON string. if you remove that char and check, it will be show as valid JSON. I verified it in https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: that was it thanks

Comment: yes but the code output does not show outputs ac_monthly values in an array. So it would be difficult to use decodable and parse it right?

Comment: No. ac_monthly is also an array of Strings/Numbers. So You can parse it as string/number array.

Comment: I cant get it parsed in jsonlit. gives erorr: Error: Parse error on line 1:
{ errors = (); inputs
--^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are converting the JSON data into an JSON object(Array, Dictionary).

But In browser the JSON data is printing as String and not as JSON object(Array, Dictionary).

So if you want to print the JSON string in your code as well, you can print as like below.

```
let string = String(data: self, encoding: .utf8)
print("JSON String:\(String(describing: string))")
```

Hope it helps.